# Aframe/Three/WebXR: disable device orientation in VR mode

Tags: three.js, aframe, virtual-reality, device-orientation, webxr

I am using AFrame 1.2.0 to develop a VR application and I am struggling with an issue for several days.
My goal is to allow the user to see a specific view that is set programmatically and that is absolutely unrelated to the current device orientation. In other words, I should:

- stop the user see the world based on its device orientation;
- force the user to see a specific point (which I set programmatically);

These steps basically mean I should be able to:

- disable the user-device rotation (UNRESOLVED for VR-Mode )
- set the view to a specific position with a "refresh" rate (DONE)

As I wrote, the issue is related to the first point: **disabling the user-device orientation** and it only affects the **VR mode**. Indeed, everything works properly when the view is NOT in VR-Mode, but when entering in VR-Mode I can't do it anymore.

I tried managing these framework/library/APIs:

- **AFrame, look-controls**: I know it is possible to disable look-controls with some properties (e.g. enabled, magicWindowTrackingEnabled, magicWindowControls): it works, but only when the view is NOT in VR-Mode; (note that hmdEnabled is no more in AFRAME from 0.8v because, as far as I understood, the introduction of WebXR does not allow to manage device directly from AFrame);
- **THREE.DeviceOrientationControls**: I know that under the hood the look-controls component uses this THREE-element, so I debugged it and tried to manage it directly (e.g. calling disconnect, dispose, enabled=false): again, it works but only when the view is NOT in VR-Mode;
- **WebXR**: at the lowest lever, WebXR is the last API used. I debugged it and I try to manage the WebXR session, but everything is in Read-Only mode and it seems there is no function to activate/deactivate device sensors.

So, here the question: how to disable the device orientation in VR mode with AFrame/THREE/WebXR or whatever?

Thank you all.